# How to store the value returned by javascript function into a php variable?

Tags: javascript, php

The output generated by the program below is Inner textjain. Fine, but I want $m php variable to be assigned the value returned from JavaScript function a().

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<?php
$name='abhi';
?>
<div id="a">

</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
function a(){
var a="jain";

<?php echo $GLOBALS['name'] ; ?>=a;
document.getElementById('a').innerHTML="Inner text"+<?php echo $name; ?>;
return <?php echo $GLOBALS['name'];?>;
}

</script>


<?php echo $n='<script type="text/javascript">'   , 'a();'   , '</script>';
echo $n;?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Concept is wrong, JS function is also wrong... try to explain what is the goal here.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. Once the page is delivered to the browser, which is where Javascript runs, your PHP server has already shut the request down. If you somehow really want to send something calculated in Javascript back to PHP, you'll have to make an additional request to the browser from Javascript (using AJAX) but even then the variable will be available in a *new* request, not the old one.

Answer (score 1):

PHP runs on the server, Javascript runs on the browser, and they don't run concurrently, so you'll have to send your Javascript variable to the PHP script (and re-run the PHP script), which involves reloading the page.

You can e.g. a GET request (by loading `script.php?yourvariable=value`).

Answer (score 0):

you can't. PHP runs at the server first and then javascript will run at client side.